# Как правильно сделать вывод из бд по нескольким критериям?

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите, хочу сделать вывод из бд по критериям:

а) logged_id = [$_SESSION['logged_user']->login] (ниже приведён работающий код):

```
$posts = R::findAll('posts', 'logged_id = ?', [$_SESSION['logged_user']->login]);
```

б) и по такому же принципу всё значение active, где есть 2 (ниже снова работающий код):

```
$posts = R::findAll('posts', 'active = 2');
```

но, если я хочу всё вместе соеденить, то уже результат не получается:

```
$posts = R::findAll('posts', 'driver = ?', [$_SESSION['logged_user']->login]);
$posts = R::findAll('posts', 'active = 2');
```

### как можно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$posts = R::findAll('posts', 'driver = ? AND active = ?', [$_SESSION['logged_user']->login, 2]);
```